# This piece of code breaks strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I read https://www.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing,
and found this piece of code.

```
QDataStream &QDataStream::operator>>(qint16 &i)
{
...
        register uchar *p = (uchar *)(&i);
        char b[2];
        if (dev->read(b, 2) == 2) {
            *p++ = b[1];
            *p = b[0];
...
```

The author claims MSVC optimizes away the assignments which I find quite strange.

Does MSVC really exploit strict aliasing rule?

And isn't uchar* specially allowed to be used to do type punning?

Comment: You do not say the version. But according to a comment from STL at microsoft. MSVC does not use strict aliasing. [See here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-1-of-n)

Comment: I don't use MSVC much and I don't know the differences between various versions of MSVC. But somehow I have the impression that they don't exploit undefined behavior. For example I never hear of integer overflow problem caused by MSVC.

Comment: I believe this code is fine. If this caused problems in MSVC, then that's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

It was either a compiler bug or a bug in the code that called this method. The "strict aliasing rule" allows the object `i` refers to be accessed using character types, regardless of what the type of that object actually is. The code that calls this method doesn't even actually have to pass an reference to an object that's compatible with `qint16` for this function to have defined behaviour.